# Shortcut keys on Acer CB3-111-670 Chromebook running Ubuntu 15.10 not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness, acer, chromebook

I have Ubuntu 15.10 running on the internal SSD of a Acer CB3-111-670 Chromebook. After some running around to fix the audio, the last thing (that I can tell) doesn't work is the shortcut keys (volume and brightness are the only ones I really care about.)  I can however, change the volume and brightness in settings using a mouse.

I believe (but am not certain,) that the shortcut keys are being recognized as f1-f12, but they don't seem to be in the correct order (off by one) and are not doing what you would expect.

For instance, if I press the 'brighten' button, which by counting the buttons starting from the far left as f1, the brightness key would be associated with f8--when pressed I get a pop-up box that says, "Pressing f7 turns caret browsing on or off..." as apposed to actually making the screen brighter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On a laptop keyboard the very top left key is often esc. Followed by f1, f2, etc.

Also the labeled shorcuts on the keys may not be the same in Ubuntu vs ChromeOS. Unless they are hardware shortcuts ubuntu likely only sees them as f-keys.

It may be possible with the help of other software to remap those keys to the shortcuts you want. For example https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/autokey-gtk/.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder, there is no fn key on my laptop, but if the keys are only being recognized as f-keys, would it be possible to use a key in conjunction with an f-key to do a shortcut? I don't really care which key or key combination I use to adjust brightness, it would just be much faster than digging through settings and using the trackpad.

Comment: I have used autohotkey for things like that. I dont know if its available for Ubuntu but if it is there are a bunch of guides on it.

Comment: You could try autokey, its in the ubuntu repos. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/autokey-gtk/